# Is this a linear programming problem

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming

If $x \in R^n$, then

> $\min \|x\|_{\infty}$
>
> sub to $Ax = b$, $x \geq 0$

where $\|x\|_{\infty}$ is the infinity norm which is $\max\{\|x_1\|,\|x_2\|,\ldots,\|x_n\|\}$.

If not then how can we convert it to LP.

My initial feeling is that it is not a LP. I can convert it to n LP problems of maximizing and then taking the minimum amongst them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Define $y$ to satisfy $$y\geq x_i\, \forall \,i.$$ Then $y=\|x\|_{\infty}$ at the optimal solution.